# where is my css coming from?

Tags: html, css, drupal

I'm creating a store for my wife in Drupal. I'm not a web person and kept things pretty vanilla except for a few changes. It's not my first Drupal site but is my first store.

Using Firebug I have found the divs and have been able to change the colors where necessary.

I now need to make one change but I can't find where the problem is.

If I open up the table I want to change the background color of in Firebug I can view the css:

[image: Firebug]

As you can see the background color reads as transparent.

If I click on the link where Firebug shows the css is coming from it points to

http://10.0.1.151/sites/default/files/css - The files in there look like caches of the css as they have very recent times and dates on.

If I change the background color temporarily using firebug:

[image: Firebug 2]

the table looks exactly how I want it.

So I guess my question is how do I make that change to the style sheet so its permanent?

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

PS. I've chopped some of the bottom of style sheet of because I'm new and the site wont let me post more.

Below is a copy of `style.css`:

```
/* $Id: style.css,v 1.1.2.11 2010/07/02 22:11:04 sociotech Exp $ */


/* Margin, Padding, Border Resets

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

html, body, div, span, p,

dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li,

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,

form, fieldset, input, textarea {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}



img, abbr, acronym {

  border: 0;

}





/* HTML Elements

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

p {

  margin: 1em 0;

}



h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {

  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;

}



ul, ol, dd {

  margin-bottom: 1.5em;

  margin-left: 2em; /* LTR */

}



li ul, li ol {

  margin-bottom: 0;

}



ul {

  list-style-type: disc;

}



ol {

  list-style-type: decimal;

}



a {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

  text-decoration: none;

}



a:link,

a:visited {

}



a:hover,

a:focus,

a:active {

  text-decoration: underline;

}



blockquote {

}



hr {

  height: 1px;

  border: 1px solid gray;

}



/* tables */

table {

  border-spacing: 0;

  width: 100%;

}



caption {

  text-align: left;

}



th {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0 10px 0 0;

}



th.active img {

  display: inline;

}



thead th {

  padding-right: 10px;

}



td {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 3px;

}



/* Remove grid block styles from Drupal's table ".block" class */

td.block {

  border: none;

  float: none;

  margin: 0;

}



/* Maintain light background/dark text on dragged table rows */

tr.drag td,

tr.drag-previous td {

  background: #FFFFDD;

  color: #000;

}





/* Accessibility

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* skip-link to main content, hide offscreen */

#skip a,

#skip a:hover,

#skip a:visited {

  height: 1px;

  left: 0px;

  overflow: hidden;

  position: absolute;

  top: -500px;

  width: 1px;

}



/* make skip link visible when selected */

#skip a:active,

#skip a:focus {

  background-color: #fff;

  color: #000;

  height: auto;

  padding: 5px 10px;

  position: absolute;

  top: 0;

  width: auto;

  z-index: 99;

}



#skip a:hover {

  text-decoration: none;

}





/* Helper Classes

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.hide {

  display: none;

  visibility: hidden;

}



.left {

  float: left;

}



.right {

  float: right;

}



.clear {

  clear: both;

}



/* clear floats after an element */

/* (also in ie6-fixes.css, ie7-fixes.css) */

.clearfix:after,

.clearfix .inner:after {

  clear: both;

  content: ".";

  display: block;

  font-size: 0;

  height: 0;

  line-height: 0;

  overflow: auto;

  visibility: hidden;

}





/* Grid Layout Basics (specifics in 'gridnn_x.css')

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* center page and full rows: override this for left-aligned page */

.page,

.row {

  margin: 0 auto;

}



/* fix layout/background display on floated elements */

.row,

.nested,

.block {

  overflow: hidden;

}



/* full-width row wrapper */

div.full-width {

  width: 100%;

}



/* float, un-center & expand nested rows */

.nested {

  float: left; /* LTR */

  margin: 0;

  width: 100%;

}



/* allow Superfish menus to overflow */

#sidebar-first.nested,

#sidebar-last.nested,

div.superfish {

  overflow: visible;

}



/* sidebar layouts */

.sidebars-both-first .content-group {

  float: right; /* LTR */

}



.sidebars-both-last .sidebar-first {

  float: right; /* LTR */

}



/* Grid Mask Overlay

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#grid-mask-overlay {

  display: none;

  left: 0;

  opacity: 0.75;

  position: absolute;

  top: 0;

  width: 100%;

  z-index: 997;

}



#grid-mask-overlay .row {

  margin: 0 auto;

}



#grid-mask-overlay .block .inner {

  background-color: #e3fffc;

  outline: none;

}



.grid-mask #grid-mask-overlay {

  display: block;

}



.grid-mask .block {

  overflow: visible;

}



.grid-mask .block .inner {

  outline: #f00 dashed 1px;

}



#grid-mask-toggle {

  background-color: #777;

  border: 2px outset #fff;

  color: #fff;

  cursor: pointer;

  font-variant: small-caps;

  font-weight: normal;

  left: 0;

  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  padding: 0 5px 2px 5px;

  position: absolute;

  text-align: center;

  top: 22px;

  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

  z-index: 998;

}



#grid-mask-toggle.grid-on {

  border-style: inset;

  font-weight: bold;

}





/* Site Info

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#header-site-info {

  width: auto;

}



#site-name-wrapper {

  float: left;   /* LTR */

}



#site-name,

#slogan {

  display: block;

}



#site-name a:link,

#site-name a:visited,

#site-name a:hover,

#site-name a:active {

  text-decoration: none;

}



#site-name a {

  outline: 0;

}





/* Regions

-------------------------------------------------------------- */



/* Header Regions

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#header-group {

  overflow: visible;

}



/* Content Regions (Main)

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.node-bottom {

  margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;

}



/*  Clear floats on regions

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#header-top-wrapper,

#header-group-wrapper,

#preface-top-wrapper,

#main-wrapper,

#preface-bottom,

#content-top,

#content-region,

#content-bottom,

#postscript-top,

#postscript-bottom-wrapper,

#footer-wrapper,

#footer-message-wrapper {

  clear: both;

}





/* Drupal Core

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */



/* Lists

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.item-list ul li {

  margin: 0;

}



.block ul,

.block ol {

  margin-left: 2em; /* LTR */

  padding: 0;

}



.content-inner ul,

.content-inner ol {

  margin-bottom: 1.5em;

}



.content-inner li ul,

.content-inner li ol {

  margin-bottom: 0;

}



.block ul.links {

  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */

}



/* Menus

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */

ul.menu li,

ul.links li {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}



/* Primary Menu

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* use ID to override overflow: hidden for .block, dropdowns should always be visible */

#primary-menu {

  overflow: visible;

}



/* remove left margin from primary menu list */

#primary-menu.block ul {

  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */

}



/* remove bullets, float left */

.primary-menu ul li {

  float: left; /* LTR */

  list-style: none;

  position: relative;

}



/* style links, and unlinked parent items (via Special Menu Items module) */

.primary-menu ul li a,

.primary-menu ul li .nolink {

  display: block;

  padding: 0.75em 1em;

  text-decoration: none;

}



/* Add cursor style for unlinked parent menu items */

.primary-menu ul li .nolink {

  cursor: default;

}



/* remove outline */

.primary-menu ul li:hover,

.primary-menu ul li.sfHover,

.primary-menu ul a:focus,

.primary-menu ul a:hover,

.primary-menu ul a:active {

  outline: 0;

}



/* Secondary Menu

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.secondary-menu-inner ul.links {

  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */

}





/* Skinr styles

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */



/* Skinr selectable helper classes */

.fusion-clear {

  clear: both;

}



div.fusion-right {

  float: right; /* LTR */

}



div.fusion-center {

  float: none;

  margin-left: auto;

  margin-right: auto;

}



.fusion-center-content .inner {

  text-align: center;

}



.fusion-center-content .inner ul.menu {

  display: inline-block;

  text-align: center;

}



/* required to override drupal core */

.fusion-center-content #user-login-form {

  text-align: center;

}



.fusion-right-content .inner {

  text-align: right; /* LTR */

}



/* required to override drupal core */

.fusion-right-content #user-login-form {

  text-align: right; /* LTR */

}



/* Large, bold callout text style */

.fusion-callout .inner {

  font-weight: bold;

}



/* Extra padding on block */

.fusion-padding .inner {

  padding: 30px;

}



/* Adds 1px border and padding */

.fusion-border .inner {

  border-width: 1px;

  border-style: solid;

  padding: 10px;

}



/* Single line menu with separators */

.fusion-inline-menu .inner ul.menu {

  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */

}



.fusion-inline-menu .inner ul.menu li {

  border-right-style: solid;

  border-right-width: 1px;

  display: inline;

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

  white-space: nowrap;

}



.fusion-inline-menu .inner ul.menu li a {

  padding: 0 8px 0 5px; /* LTR */

}



.fusion-inline-menu .inner ul li.last {

  border: none;

}



/* Hide second level (and beyond) menu items */

.fusion-inline-menu .inner ul li.expanded ul {

  display: none;

}



/* Multi-column menu style with bolded top level menu items */

.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul {

  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */

  text-align: left; /* LTR */

}



.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul li {

  border-right: none;

  display: block;

  font-weight: bold;

}



.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul li.last {

  border-right: none;

}



.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul li.last a {

  padding-right: 0; /* LTR */

}



.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul li.expanded,

.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul li.leaf {

  float: left; /* LTR */

  list-style-image: none;

  margin-left: 50px; /* LTR */

}



.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul.menu li.first {

  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */

}



.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul li.expanded li.leaf {

  float: none;

  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */

}



.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul li.expanded ul {

  display: block;

  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */

}



.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul li.expanded ul li {

  border: none;

  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */

  text-align: left; /* LTR */

}



.fusion-multicol-menu .inner ul.menu li ul.menu li {

  font-weight: normal;

}



/* Split list across multiple columns */

.fusion-2-col-list .inner .item-list ul li,

.fusion-2-col-list .inner ul.menu li {

  float: left; /* LTR */

  width: 50%;

}



.fusion-3-col-list .inner .item-list ul li,

.fusion-3-col-list .inner ul.menu li {

  float: left; /* LTR */

  width: 33%;

}



.fusion-2-col-list .inner .item-list ul.pager li,

.fusion-3-col-list .inner .item-list ul.pager li {

  float: none;

  width: auto;

}



/* List with bottom border

    Fixes a common issue when list items have bottom borders and appear to be

    doubled when nested lists end and begin. This removes the extra border-bottom

 */

.fusion-list-bottom-border .inner ul li {

  list-style: none;

  list-style-type: none;

  list-style-image: none;

}



.fusion-list-bottom-border .inner ul li,

.fusion-list-bottom-border .view-content div.views-row {

  padding: 0 0 0 10px; /* LTR */

  border-bottom-style: solid;

  border-bottom-width: 1px;

  line-height: 216.7%; /* 26px */

}



.fusion-list-bottom-border .inner ul {

  margin: 0;

}



.fusion-list-bottom-border .inner ul li ul {

  border-bottom-style: solid;

  border-bottom-width: 1px;

}



.fusion-list-bottom-border .inner ul li ul li.last {

  border-bottom-style: solid;

  border-bottom-width: 1px;

  margin-bottom: -1px;

  margin-top: -1px;

}



/*Andrew

*/

#views_slideshow_singleframe_pager_slideshow-page_2 .pager-item {

display:block;

}



#views_slideshow_singleframe_pager_slideshow-page_2 {

position:absolute;

right:0;

top:0;

}



#header-group-wrapper {

background-color:#92bbe9;

}



#main-wrapper {

background-color:#F3F3F3;

background-image:url('http://10.0.1.151/sites/all/themes/fusion/fusion_core/images/backgroundmain.jpg');

background-repeat:no-repeat;

background-attachment: fixed;

width: auto;

}



/.front {

/background-color:#F3F3F3;

/background-image:url('http://10.0.1.151/sites/all/themes/fusion/fusion_core/images/background.jpg');

/background-repeat:no-repeat;

/background-attachment: fixed;

/width: auto;

/}



#views_slideshow_singleframe_pager_slideshow-page_2 div a img {

top:0px;

height:60px;

width:80px;

padding-right:10px;

padding-bottom:19px;

}



#mycontent{

width: 720px;

}



#block-views-new_products-block_1{

height:200px;

}



/* List with no bullet and extra padding

    This is a common style for menus, which removes the bullet and adds more

    vertical padding for a simple list style

 */

.fusion-list-vertical-spacing .inner ul,

.fusion-list-vertical-spacing div.views-row-first {

  margin-left: 0;

  margin-top: 10px;

}



.fusion-list-vertical-spacing .inner ul li,

.fusion-list-vertical-spacing div.views-row {

  line-height: 133.3%; /* 16px/12px */

  margin-bottom: 10px;

  padding: 0;

}



.fusion-list-vertical-spacing .inner ul li {

  list-style: none;

  list-style-image: none;

  list-style-type: none;

}



.fusion-list-vertical-spacing .inner ul li ul {

  margin-left: 10px; /* LTR */

}



/* Bold all links */

.fusion-bold-links .inner a {

  font-weight: bold;

}



/* Float imagefield images left and add margin */

.fusion-float-imagefield-left .field-type-filefield,

.fusion-float-imagefield-left .image-insert,

.fusion-float-imagefield-left .imagecache {

  float: left; /* LTR */

  margin: 0 15px 15px 0; /* LTR */

}



/* Clear float on new Views item so each row drops to a new line */

.fusion-float-imagefield-left .views-row {

  clear: left; /* LTR */

}



/* Float imagefield images right and add margin */

.fusion-float-imagefield-right .field-type-filefield,

.fusion-float-imagefield-right .image-insert

.fusion-float-imagefield-right .imagecache {

  float: right; /* LTR */

  margin: 0 0 15px 15px; /* LTR */

}



/* Clear float on new Views item so each row drops to a new line */

.fusion-float-imagefield-right .views-row {

  clear: right; /* LTR */

}



/* Superfish: all menus */

.sf-menu li {

  list-style: none;

  list-style-image: none;

  list-style-type: none;

}



/* Superfish: vertical menus */

.superfish-vertical {

  position: relative;

  z-index: 9;

}



ul.sf-vertical {

  background: #fafafa;

  margin: 0;

  width: 100%;

}



ul.sf-vertical li {

  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

  font-weight: bold;

  line-height: 200%; /* 24px */

  padding: 0;

  width: 100%;

}



ul.sf-vertical li a:link,

ul.sf-vertical li a:visited,

ul.sf-vertical li .nolink {

  margin-left: 10px;

  padding: 2px;

}



ul.sf-vertical li a:hover,

ul.sf-vertical li a.active {

  text-decoration: underline;

}



ul.sf-vertical li ul {

  background: #fafafa;

  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;

  margin-left: 0;

  width: 150px;

}



ul.sf-vertical li ul li.last {

  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;

  margin-bottom: -1px;

  margin-top: -1px;

}



ul.sf-vertical li ul {

  border-top: none;

  padding: 4px 0;

}



ul.sf-vertical li ul li {

  border-bottom: none;

  line-height: 150%; /* 24px */

}



ul.sf-vertical li ul li.last {

  border-top: none;

}



ul.sf-vertical li ul li ul {

  margin-top: -4px;

}





/* Pagers

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

ul.pager {

  margin: 20px 0;

}



ul.pager li {

  margin: 0;

  white-space: nowrap;

}



ul.pager a,

ul.pager li.pager-current {

  border-style: solid;

  border-width: 1px;

  padding: 3px 6px 2px 6px;

  text-decoration: none;

}



ul.pager a:link,

ul.pager a:visited {

  color: inherit;

}



ul.pager a:hover,

ul.pager a:active,

ul.pager a:focus {

  border-style: solid;

  border-width: 1px;

}



ul.pager span.pager-ellipsis {

  padding: 0 4px;

}



.item-list .pager li {

  padding: 0;

}





/* Forms

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* defaults for all text fields */

.form-text {

  padding: 2px;

}



/* defaults for all form buttons */

form input.form-submit {

  cursor: pointer;

  font-weight: bold;

  margin: 2px;

  padding: 3px 5px;

}



form input.form-submit:hover {

  cursor: pointer;

}



fieldset {

  margin: 15px 0;

  padding: 10px;

}



html.js fieldset.collapsed {

  margin-bottom: 15px;

}



/* limit width of form inputs */

textarea,

.form-item input,

.form-item select,

#content-region input.form-text {

  max-width: 95%;

}



html.js textarea {

  max-width: 100%;

}



/* adjust for collapsible fieldset differences */

fieldset.collapsible .resizable-textarea textarea {

  max-width: 101.5%;

}



fieldset.collapsible .resizable-textarea .grippie {

  width: 101%;

}



/* keep admin pages visible */

.page-admin #main-content-inner .nested,

.page-admin #content-group,

.page-admin #content-region,

.page-admin #content-inner {

  margin-bottom: 1.5em;

  overflow: visible;

}



/* keep admin form elements on top */

.page-admin .content-inner-inner {

  z-index: 10;

}



/* theme settings form field width limit */

form#system-theme-settings select,

form#system-theme-settings input.form-text {

  max-width: 95%;

}



/* keep theme select form visible */

#system-themes-form {

  position: relative;

  z-index: 1;

}



/* keep theme switcher visible */

.form-item select#edit-theme {

  max-width: none;

}



/* keep admin columns from dropping under */

div.admin .left,

div.admin .right {

  margin-left: 1%;

  margin-right: 1%;

}



/* region labels on block admin page */

.block-region {

  background-color: #F3F3F3;

  border: 3px dashed #CCCCCC;

  color: #555555;

  font-weight: bold;

  margin: 1px;

  padding: 3px;

  text-align: center;

  text-shadow: 1px 1px #FDFDFD;

  text-transform: uppercase;

  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

}





/* User Login Form

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* remove centering on login form */

#user-login-form {

  text-align: left; /* LTR */

}



#user-login-form .item-list {

  margin-top: 1em;

}



#user-login-form .item-list ul {

  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */

}



/* remove list styling on login form */

#user-login-form div.item-list ul li {

  list-style-type: none;

  margin: 0;

}



/* adjust openid link (display set in openid.js) */

#user-login-form li.openid-link a,

#user-login li.openid-link a {

  background-position: 0 0;

  padding: 0 0 0 20px;

}



/* User Login Form - Horizontal (Skinr selectable)

/-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.fusion-horiz-login#block-user-0 {

  float: right;

  margin: 20px 0 10px 0;

  position: relative;

}



html.js .fusion-horiz-login#block-user-0 {

  margin-top: 10px;

}



.fusion-horiz-login#block-user-0 h2.title {

  display: none;

}



.fusion-horiz-login#block-user-0 #user-login-form div.form-item,

.fusion-horiz-login#block-user-0 #user-login-form input.form-submit,

.fusion-horiz-login#block-user-0 .item-list {

  float: left;

  margin: 0 10px 0 0;

  text-align: left;

}

--- chopped
```

Comment: @Andrew, If you can edit the question to remove the entire CSS and just add the part about `even` or `odd` classes and the styles for the class `category`, it would be very useful. At the moment it is very hard to follow the entire stylesheet. Also do you want the background colour to be white or transparent?

Comment: @Andrew: I have edited your question a lot to restore some of the intended layout you had down, do take time to familiarise yourself with the editor and Markdown over time.

Comment: @sarcastyx: The CSS file is kind of trivial, FireBug has the file and class declaration you need to make the modifications necessary. Just have to look in _that_ file for _that_ line and change (since that's last one in the cascade).

Comment: @Andrew: I have left the link "http://10.0.1.151/sites/default/files/css" in, as it belongs to a sentence - but note that this is an *internal* IP address for your personal network, not visible externally to others - a [Private Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

Comment: @Brad Christie, that is what I thought. But I could not find any mention of `tr.even td` in his stylesheet. Which is why I asked for a limited set. And now I see what was/is happening.

Answer (score 7):

Turn off css aggregation in your /admin/settings/performance page. That will give you a much better view of where the css is coming from. In your styles.css in your theme you should be able to override whatever is coming before it. In other words: it doesn't really matter where the css is coming from, you simply need to put the css you want in your theme's style.css file.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe this depends on your particular theme, so the URL to the resource would be helpful if it is live.

That said, I found the styling for tr.even for my site under:

drupal_Folder/themes/the_theme_name_I_am_using/css/style.css

I also believe that if you mouse over the blue "css_f4...." item that it will show you the name of the file that that particular CSS is in.